# How can i pass value in a class?? JAVA

Tags: java, class, paint, draw

How can I pass value in a class?

I try to draw bar-charts for each key-value of the array.

So, I have to pass (int) len through class `Grid`.
How can I find a solution here?
Thanks in advance :)

So here is my code:

```
int len; 

public void HistogramGen() {

    JFrame framegraph = new JFrame("Terms Histogram");  
    framegraph.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
    framegraph.pack(); 
    framegraph.setVisible(true); 

    JPanel p= new JPanel( new GridLayout(finalnumber, 3) );

    for(int m=0; m<finalnumber; ++m) {
        p.add( new JLabel((String)keys[m]) );
        p.add( new JLabel( ((Integer)values[m]).toString() ) );
        String bar= "";
        for(int n=0; n<(Integer)values[m]; ++n) {
            bar= bar + "_";
        }
        len=bar.length();
        p.add( new Grid() ); 
    }

    JScrollPane pane= new JScrollPane( p );
    framegraph.add( pane );
}


public static class Grid extends JComponent {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(0, 0, len, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, len, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, unless you need to access `Grid` from a static context, it doesn't have to be `static`. If you remove that, it should be easy to access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call paint to draw bar charts? JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174269/how-can-i-call-paint-to-draw-bar-charts-java)

Answer (score 0):

add constructor to your Grid class like this:

```
public static class Grid extends JComponent {
    private final int len;
    public Grid(final int len) {
        super();

        this.len = len;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    ...
}
```

then change you caller code

```
p.add( new Grid(bar.length()) );
```